# cannot invoke remote function inside match : Foreach loop

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to set some property of User model inside a for-each loop, But I keep getting following error

> **cannot invoke remote function x.token/0 inside match**
>   (elixir) src/elixir_fn.erl:9: anonymous fn/3 in :elixir_fn.translate/3
>       (stdlib) lists.erl:1353: :lists.mapfoldl/3
>       (elixir) src/elixir_fn.erl:14: :elixir_fn.translate/3

Method:

```
Enum.each(users, fn(user) ->
  user.token = Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(to_string(user.id))
end)
```

Comment: did you import Comeonin.Bcrypt? If you did you can call hashpwsalt without the prefix which may be causing you problem.

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff tried that, still not working

Comment: Here https://hexdocs.pm/comeonin/Comeonin.Bcrypt.html it says there is a function init() - does that need to be called before invoking hashpwsalt ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a few issues here. The `=` operator is the *match* operator, it is not assignment. To explain the error, syntax-wise, this looks like function invocation on the left hand side of a match, which is not allowed.

But this is besides the point of your actual goal. If you want a set of user models that are updated with the new bcrypt information, you need to use a map function:

```
users = Enum.map(users, fn %User{id: id}=user ->
          %User{user| token: Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt("#{id}")}
        end)
```

You have to remember that everything in Elixir is immutable.