# Cannot invoke local inside match

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I have a simple module responsible for communicating with an API. As a convenience to the user, I allow users to pass a "short" url `/my/route` or the full url `https://api.mysite.com` and handle it with `HTTPoison`'s `process_url` method:

```
defmodule MyApp.MyApiHandler do
  use HTTPoison.base
  @endpoint = "https://api.mysite.com"

  def process_url(@endpoint <> _path = url), do: url
  def process_url(url), do: @endpoint <> url
end
```

This works perfectly! Urls that start with the endpoint are unmodified, and those don't have endpoint added.

The issue I'm encountering is when I try to move this endpoint from a module attribute to a method that reads from config at run time:

```
defmodule MyApp.MyApiHandler do
  use HTTPoison.base

  def process_url(endpoint() <> _path = url), do: url
  def process_url(url), do: endpoint() <> url

  defp endpoint do
    Application.get_env(:MyApp, __MODULE__)[:endpoint]
  end
end
```

I receive the following error

```
lib/my_api_handler.ex: cannot invoke local endpoint/0 inside match, called as endpoint()
```

I'd really prefer to store this config in config (so I can change it per environment). Is there a way to do that while preserving the matching?

The existing [SO question for this error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35684932/1048479) doesn't seem to cover my use case (I'm not attempting to assign in the match) but I could also be wrong there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two answers posted already will fetch the env variable at compile time instead of run time which means if you change the value using `Application.put_env`, the function will keep on using the old value. The simplest way I can think of to implement this with a value that can change at run time would be to use `String.starts_with?/2`:

```
def process_url(url) do
  endpoint = Application.get_env(...)
  if String.starts_with?(url, endpoint), do: url, else: endpoint <> url
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define `endpoint` as a macro.

E.g,

```
defmodule Test do
  defmacro endpoint do
    Application.get_env(:MyApp, __MODULE__)[:endpoint]
  end
  def process_url(endpoint() <> _path = url), do: url
  def process_url(url), do: endpoint() <> url
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Put it in the `module attribute`:

```
@endpoint Application.get_env(:MyApp, __MODULE__)[:endpoint]
```